# NEST for ElasticSearch: incorrect name of execution_hint

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Looks like there is a problem with NEST library for ElasticSearch:

```
aggs = aggs.Terms(facetName, s => s.Field(facetName).Size(facetMaxCount).ExecutionHint(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.Map));
```

creates query:

```
"terms": {
    "field": "markets",
    "size": 20,
    "execution_hit": "map"
  }
```

execution_hit should be execution_hint, any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1174) and will be available in our next release.  In the mean time, you can grab our bleeding edge package from: https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net